# lodash filter multiple matchesProperty

Tags: javascript, lodash

So i am attempting to filter my collection using the following template:

```
// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.filter(users, ['active', false]);
// => objects for ['fred']
```

So say for instance i have the following object:

```
{
    name: 'Marc'
  user: {
        division:{
            id: 1
      }
  },
  status:0
}
```

And in my array i have many different instances of this object.

Now i wish to filter my array to only contain objects where `status = 1` and `user.division.id = 1`

You would think that you would type something like this:

```
_.filter(myArr, ['user.division.id', 1], ['status', 1])
```

However this does not work :(

I have also attempted:

```
_.filter(myArr, ['user.division.id', 12,'status', 1])
```

Again with same result.

Both of these only evaluate the first expression (ie):

```
_.filter(myArr, ['user.division.id', 1])
```

It seems the second expression is never evaluated.

So my question is how can you do this with multiple matches?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `_.matchesProperty` syntax? Isn't `_.matches` more appropriate here? Although I'm not sure if you can use a flattened key there.

Comment: i am able to use a flattened key however im not able to use multiple keys

Comment: If you do `_.filter(users, { 'user': { 'division': { 'id':  1}}, 'status': 1})` then you can do multi-parameter matching. This is the `_.matches` syntax where you give the function an object of what it needs to match. I don't think `matchesProprty` allows for multiple keys/values to be supplied.

Comment: @vlaz sadly due to the complication of the directive im making i will need to use multiple key/value pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so as @valz pointed out i was unable to use multiple key/values in `matchesProperty`

So what i did was the following:

```
var filters = {'user.division.id': 1, status:1}
_.forEach(filters, function(value, key) {
    data = _.filter(data, [key,value]);
});
```

Comment: How to filter using case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

`_.filter` either accepts:

1. A single multi-level path and its value (as an array of 2 elements).
2. A flat object with one-level keys and values.
3. A nested object with keys and values.

So if we want to use a **flat path-based filter**, we can zip it into a **nested object** to make use of (3):

```
function filterDeep(collection, filters) {
  return _.filter(
    collection,
    _.zipObjectDeep(_.keys(filters), _.values(filters)),
  );
}
```